# Change widget appearance without using css

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Is it possible to change widget appearance (border color) in GWT without using css file?
I know that some components have methods like setBodyStyle(String style) which can be used instead of css files, but Widget class doesn't have this method.

EDIT:
I'm rewriting a project and it was made like this:

```
public void changeActiveWidget(Widget newActiveWidget) {
        newActiveWidget.removeStyleName("inactive-area");
        newActiveWidget.addStyleName("active-area");
        if (activeWidget != null) {
            activeWidget.removeStyleName("active-area");
            activeWidget.addStyleName("inactive-area");
        }

        activeWidget = newActiveWidget;
    }
```

where inactive-area is gray border and active-area is red border which are defined in css file. Now I would like to do it without css file and I hae no idea how.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your current code, what it does, and what you have tried to get it where you want it.

Comment: I would suggest to add CSS files, instead of handwriting it to the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is very nasty (what you are describing sounds also wrong :) but you can access the widget's main element [UIObject.html#getElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#getElement()) and from there you can change its properties, including style: [Element.html#getStyle](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getStyle())

```
public void changeActiveWidget(Widget newActiveWidget) { 
    newActiveWidget.getElement().getStyle().setBorderColor("WhiteSmoke");
}
```

Comment: `public void changeActiveWidget(Widget newActiveWidget) {
        newActiveWidget.getElement().getStyle().setBorder(...)`


Was about to answer, but your answer is nearly finished. May be a code example?